# Trying To pass list of data in from controller to partial view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass list of data through viewbag  from controller to partial view but getting error

in login form after submitting data taking it from formcollection through HttPost and once action complete it return to home page from there i am calling method Page_Init inside that in  'loadmessage' method i am trying to return list to a partial view "Header" based on condition.but not able to perform getting error

Home controller
[HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
{
 return View("Home");
}
```

in Home.cshtml
calling method page_init in controller

```
$.get("/Home/Page_Init",null, function (data) {
           alert(data);
       });
```

Home controller

```
 public ActionResult Page_Init()
    {
     loadMessages();
     return view("Home");
    }

public ActionResult loadMessages()
{
 List<MessageModel> lstMessages = new List<MessageModel>();
 List<MessageModel> lstInfoMessages = new List<MessageModel>();
lstInfoMessages = lstMessages.Where(msg => msg.MESSAGE_TYPE.Equals(CommonConstants.SAFETY_MESSAGE_INFO, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList<MessageModel>();
if (lstInfoMessages.Count > 0)
{
 ViewBag.lstInfoMessages = 1;
 ViewBag.lstInfoMessages1 = lstInfoMessages;
 return PartialView("Header", lstInfoMessages);
}

}
```

also trying to go to partial view from Home view

```
@ViewBag.lstInfoMessages1
@if (ViewBag.lstInfoMessages == 1)
{
    @Html.Partial("Header",ViewBag.lstInfoMessages1)
}
```

Expected that list of information should go to partial view and bind
Error:Not getting Exact syntax what to do and how to proceed the steps tried above throw error

Comment: without knowing the error message, its hard to help But I guess, return statement is missing in Page_Init action, (you probably getting build error).

Comment: @sam return message is there  but what could be best way to send list of data to partial using viewbag. directly from controller method or through view.

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.Partial` method does not accept the dynamic value – so we need to cast it to the actual type.

```
@model MessageModel   //you need to give correct path of MessageModel
@ViewBag.lstInfoMessages1
@if (ViewBag.lstInfoMessages == 1)
{
    @Html.Partial("Header", (List<MessageModel>)ViewBag.lstInfoMessages1)
}
```

In Header Partial view, you can retrieve list using `@Model`

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned but it is giving error  "the type or Name sapce 'MessageModel' could not be found(are you missing using directive or assemblie refrence)

Comment: @model MessageModel   //you need to give the correct path of MessageModel  on Home view as well as Header View

Comment: where you define MessageModel ?